# Mouse click sometimes causes keyboard input, how?

Tags: javascript, html, events, mouse

Let me explain my situation... I'm making a 2D platformer game, where you can go around and shoot stuff. Going around uses W, A & D keys, and shooting is done with the mouse. When I do all of the actions separately, everything works, but when I click the mouse button, and press a key in the same time, my code starts acting as if the key was still pushed down. This happens only sometimes.

I register all the keyboard events like this:

```
<body onload="init()" onkeydown="press(event);" onkeyup="release(event);">
```

Here's the script that handles that:

```
var KEY = {W: 87, A: 65, S:83, D: 68, E: 69};

var input = {
    right: false,
    up: false,
    left: false,
    down: false,
    e: false
};

function press(evt) {
    var code = evt.keyCode;

    switch(code) 
    {
        case KEY.W: input.up = true; break;
        case KEY.A: input.left = true; break;
        case KEY.S: input.down = true; break;
        case KEY.D: input.right = true; break;
        case KEY.E: input.e = true; break;
    }
}

function release(evt)
{
    var code = evt.keyCode; 
    input.code = code;

    switch(code) 
    {
        case KEY.W: input.up = false; break;
        case KEY.A: input.left = false; break;
        case KEY.S: input.down = false; break;
        case KEY.D: input.right = false; break;        
        case KEY.E: input.e = false; break;
    }
}
```

Even when I don't register mouse events, this happens. Can someone explain why? And how do I fix this?

Comment: You're hitting your mouse too hard.

Comment: Have you tested this in multiple browsers? Sounds like a bug.

Comment: Where's the event handling code for the mouse events?

Comment: You should not pass event-object through handler function's arguments. Retrieve event in actual handler.

Comment: Yes, I have tested in both Firefox and Chrome, but I'm not sure of their versions. I also tested it on a small example from a credible source, here: http://nokarma.org/examples/player_input/version_2.html. It happens in both browsers as well. I'm not sure what you're trying to say, @Teemu, and a simple code example would be great. Lol Steve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

It seems, that the jerky behavior is not occasionally. If you press and keep `left` and then press `up` and release `left`, the movement continues. But, if you release `up` after a while, movement will stop. Ie. you can make continuous circular moves, but you can't get back to the original direction. This perhaps dues to the eventhandling process, using stack-type saving for event calls and their return-points.

Below is an example code, which does the trick. It uses arrow-keys to move the spot. The code is in global space for clarity, and done for IE only, but you just edit it as you wish.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function move(elem){
    if(i[37])elem.style.left=elem.style.pixelLeft-2;
    if(i[38])elem.style.top=elem.style.pixelTop-2;
    if(i[39])elem.style.left=elem.style.pixelLeft+2;
    if(i[40])elem.style.top=elem.style.pixelTop+2;
    return;
}   

function keyDn(){
    var key=window.event.keyCode;
    if(i[key]!==undefined) i[key]=true;
    return;
}

function keyUp(){
    var key=window.event.keyCode;
    if(i[key]!==undefined) i[key]=false;
    return;
}

window.onload=function (){
    spot=document.getElementById('movablespot');
    i={'37':false,'38':false,'39':false,'40':false};
    document.body.onkeydown=keyDn;
    document.body.onkeyup=keyUp;    
    a=setInterval(function (){move(spot);return;},5);
}    
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="movablespot" style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px;">O</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cool, it doesn't seem to happen now. I've added the listeners through `addEventListener`.

Comment: Hmm, it still seems to be happening! I'll check, maybe it's just a local problem. If so, I'll accept your answer again.